# Official spring-boot SSL examples failing

Tags: spring-boot

I'm finding that the SSL examples provided in the spring-boot project are not working for me.

For this example:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/1.5.x/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-tomcat-ssl/src/main/java/sample/tomcat/ssl

And this example:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/1.5.x/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-tomcat-multi-connectors

Instead of getting 'hello world', I get

[image]

The startup log does not seem to show any issues.

Do these sample projects work for others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, it works well. Here is what I did:

Clone the Spring Boot repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot
```

Checkout the 1.5.7 branch

```
git checkout v1.5.7.RELEASE
```

Build

```
mvn package
```

Run

```
java -jar target/spring-boot-sample-tomcat-ssl-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar
```

Then open a browser on https://localhost:8443, accept the self-signed certificate and read the hello word message.

P.S.: I'm using Oracle JDK 1.8.0_144 and maven 3.5.0

Comment: Thank you! Definitely a mupetism on my part. The step I fell short on was the last one, open a browser to https://localhost:8443. It was late at night, and I was opening to http://localhost:8443 (without the s on the end of http)